# Powershell asking for confirmation before executing the code in allsigned execution mode

Tags: powershell, certificate, code-signing

We have purchased Thawte code signing certificate and am able to sign scripts with that. In all signed execution policy mode, powershell still asks for confirmation on servers before running the code. I need to run this code as scheduled job on many servers and was wondering if their is any workaround this.

In my search it seems like that the certificate needs to be in trusted publisher before execution of scripts. I could not find any scripts that can place certificate in TrustedPublisher on a remote server.

Thank you for all the help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell Help about execution policies easily found by `PS C:\>help about_Execution_Policies` shows that in AllSigned mode it will Prompt you before running scripts from Publishers that you have not yet classified as trusted or untrusted. You can try RemoteSigned or try this wonderfully explainedby Scott Hanselman http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx

> Signed scripts can be transported by exporting (from original
>   computer) and importing (to the new computer) the Powershell
>   certificates found in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities
>   container.  Optionally, the Trusted Publishers can also be moved to
>   prevent the first-time prompt.

Final note on the blog

> Note that Powershell will prompt you the first time it’s run unless
>   you also import the Trusted Publishers certificate.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but the problem remains. I have about 100 servers and it will be really time consuming to run the script first time manually on each of them or to import the certificate. The only solution I am pondering is to come up with batch script to import certificate and schedule the script remotely on all the servers

Comment: @user984201 You can deploy certificates via group policies.